# Adding elements using JQuery with many returns lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add the following code to the end of a div later on using appendTo. Here is what the code originally looks like:

```
<div class="blah">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the elements are beautifully nested. But, when I add them to my Javascript, the only way that I store the above code in a variable is when I delete all the whitespace, which erases all my wonderful nesting and readability:

```
var $addElem = $('<div class="blah"><div class="foo"><div class="bar"></div></div></div>');
```

As you can imagine, this makes it a pain in the ass to manage. Is there anyway around this?

Thanks!

Edit: It doesn't seem to be working. I am trying to append it to the end of a container.
Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/html" id="profile">
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var $image = $('#profile').html();
$image.appendTo('#container');
```

Comment: Did you look at jQuery templates. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Comment: @Cybernate, post that as an answer and I will upvote.

Comment: I'd take a couple steps back and ask myself why I have to generate all this markup in Javascript... It's going to be a pain in the ass to manage regardless of how pretty you make it!

Comment: I want to append it into a container later on.

Comment: Your appendTo call is incorrect - you are calling the method on $image which is just a string of HTML rather than a jQuery object. Try $('#container').append($image);  (you might even want to rename $image to imageHtml to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to stick the markup in a hidden div on the page and extract from there via jQuery. For example:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="display:none;">
    <div class="blah">
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $addElem = $('#placeholder').html();
</script>
```

**Edit**: Whilst the above is a quick and simple solution to your request, in response to @d_r_w's points in the comments, you might like to try the following as an alternative. This puts you one step on the road to using full template rendering:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <div class="blah">
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    $addElem = $('#template').html();
</script>
```

Browsers will ignore the contents of the script tag as they won't know how to handle them. The flipside to this is that depending on what editor you use, you may also lose colour syntax highlighting etc. Like I said before, the top solution might be the easiest approach in this situation, though I would certainly recommend you look more into using full templating. I personally am very fond of [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com).

Comment: That can lead to unexpected effects on browsers without CSS support, or with stylesheets turned off.

Comment: @d_r_w: With the user already using the classes for the div elements, it will lead to unexpected results anyway on browsers without CSS support

Comment: @d_r_w: What you say is true, there are definitely better ways of doing this (e.g. templating), this is just one simple option that I suspect would probably suffice in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $addElem = $('<div class="blah">' +
    '<div class="foo">' +
        '<div class="bar"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>');
```

Or did you mean in your resulting HTML? Add \r\n and \t as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it nested and readable as follows:

```
var $addElem = $($('<div>', {
    class: 'blah',
    html: $('<div>', {
        class: 'foo',
        html: $('<div>', {
            class: 'bar',
            html: 'whatever'
        })
    })
}));

$('body').append($addElem);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AMfrU/

Answer (score -2):

Don't delete the whitespace?

```
var $addElem = $('<div class="blah">'
               + '  <div class="foo">'
               + '    <div class="bar">'
               + '    </div>'
               + '  </div>'
               + '</div>');
```

Comment: This was the whole premise of my problem.... It doesn't work if I do this. I am forced to delete all the whitespace.